# Custom UITableViewCell NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TodoListTableIdentifier = @"TodoListTableIdentifier";
    TodoTableViewCellController *cell = (TodoTableViewCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TodoListTableIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TodoTableViewCellController" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];  
    }
    Todo *todo = [self.allTodoArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    cell.titleLabel.text = todo.fileTitle;
    cell.money.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monei:%f",todo.amount];
    cell.name.text = todo.realName;
    cell.date.text = todo.operateTime;

    return cell;
 }
```

when running :

```
 NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TodoTableViewCellController" owner:self options:nil];
```

and there is an exception: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date.'

I dont know why is happen , so please help me with this, thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error means that you have connected something to an outlet called date in your nib but that outlet does not exist.  Where do you declare date?

Comment: data is a label of the custom cell,and I declare it in the TodoTableViewCellController.h

Comment: next question, where do you call loadNibNamed?

Comment: It's date, and now I change it'name to dateLabel...and check out the nib file, there is no problem.

Comment: I dont understand what "where do you call loadNibNamed" mean? I call this function in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.I change the name ,but same excaption, "for the key date"

Comment: OK,I made a mistake : dateLabel connected to the file's owner, it should connect to the CellController! Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

1. Set `Custom Class` of File's Owner to `UITableViewCell`.
2. Set `Custom Class` of cell to your custom table view cell class `myCustomCell`.
3. Outlet your `UIlabel` in `myCustomCell.h`.

Comment: Thanks, this comments saved me!

Comment: This was the answer to my issue. I had set the File's Owner Custom Class to my own class and connected the outlets to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hook up all of your outlets in TododTableViewController XIB (particularly the view outlet), and run again.